# c++ Не работает Regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения, c++-cli

Хочу получить все элементы и вывести их в текстовое поле, но Regex не работает. Регулярное выражение в html данные ищет если проверить на сайте

```
WebClient^ wb = gcnew WebClient();
        String^ line = wb->DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=c++")->ToString();
        std::regex r("url?q=(.*?);");
        string lineUrl = marshal_as<string>(line);
        for (std::sregex_iterator i = std::sregex_iterator(lineUrl.begin(), lineUrl.end(), r);
            i != std::sregex_iterator();
            ++i)
        {
            std::smatch m = *i;
            String^ result = marshal_as<String^>(m.str() + "\n");
            textBox2->AppendText(result);
        }
```

Решение для C++\CLI

```
private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e) {
        WebClient^ wb = gcnew WebClient();
        String^ line = wb->DownloadString("https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2B%2B+cli&sxsrf=ALiCzsbGjwqdu8lXP9KlW63ZU4iPMwrQjw%3A1658238084175&ei=hLTWYo2bCtGRrgTzjIWIDQ&ved=0ahUKEwiN7dafioX5AhXRiIsKHXNGAdEQ4dUDCA4&uact=5&oq=c%2B%2B+cli&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBAgjECcyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyCggAEIAEEIcCEBQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgcIABBHELADSgQIQRgASgQIRhgAULUDWNEKYM0WaAFwAXgAgAGNDIgB-ieSAQc2LTEuMi4xmAEAoAEByAECwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz")->ToString();
        Regex^ regex = gcnew Regex("<div class=\"yuRUbf\"><a href=\"(.*?)\" data-ved");
        Match^ match = regex->Match(line);
        textBox2->AppendText(match->Groups[1]->Value + "\n"); // Вывод первого вхождения
        for (Match^ match = regex->Match(line);
            match->Success; match = match->NextMatch())
        {
            if (match->Value->Length > 0)
            {
                textBox2->AppendText(match->Groups[1]->Value + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
```

В цикле выводим все значения

Comment: Мне кажется, что у Вас неправильно распознаётся вопросительный знак между `url` и остальной частью — regex считает это как за отдельную одноимённую команду. Вы пробовали экранировать знак как `\?` => `"url\?q=(.*?);"

Comment: @4500zenja попробовал экранировать вопросительный знак, не помогло.

Comment: C++ и C++/CLI - это два разных языка. Зачем вы их смешиваете? Более того, зачем вы тратите время на освоение C++/CLI - на этом языке не пишут полноценные приложения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov в данный момент смешивают, так как с формой работать удобно. На обычных плюсах, с формой не до конца разобрался

Comment: На C# с формой работать ещё удобнее.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov знаю, там с этим проще простого. Но сейчас c++ учу. С формами нужно подружиться, если не C++\CLI, то нужно разобраться в обычном C++ как именно формы создавать

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можете пожалуйста посоветовать ide для c++ кроме Builder, так как для работы с тем же WebClient все примеры только с C++\CLI находил.

Comment: Естественно, ведь `WebClient` - это класс из .NET.

Comment: Выполните в браузере запрос `https://www.google.com/search?q=c++`, откройте исходный код страницы, попробуйте найти (Ctrl+F) на странице текст `url?q`. А нет его!

Answer (score 0):

```
"url?q=(.*?);"
    ^------------ а экранировать кто будет?
            ^---- это тут вообще что забыло?
```

PS: И вообще, нафига использовать std::regex с .net'ными строками вместо .net'ных регулярок?

Comment: ♦  выражение составлено правильно, то что знак вопросительный нужно экранировать первый раз слышу, всегда работало без него. ^---- это тут вообще что забыло? это часть регулярки. 
И перед  std::regex я перевел net ные строки в обычные

Comment: @ИванРудаков - выражение составлено неверно. [Квантификация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Регулярные_выражения#Квантификация_(поиск_последовательностей)). Символы `?`, `+`, `*` - это ж азы регулярок.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov на шарпе это всегда игнорировалось

Comment: @ИванРудаков - нет, вы ошибаетесь.

Comment: @ИванРудаков, а слабо показать, как же оно там игнорировалось?